# Как правильно прописать hover для блока и для ссылки под ней?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня есть макет, и в нем вот такие блоки с картинками, одни показаны без наведения на них, а один показан как должно быть при наведении на один из 6ти блоков
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал делать это при помощи hover нашел пример на codepen, но у меня почему-то не работает
код прилагается

```css
.card1 {
  width: 314px;
  height: 262px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.img-background {
  width: 314px;
  height: 205px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 17px 24px #000000;
}

.card-img {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  width: 307px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.card-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block_drop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #5751C1;
  transition-property: margin-top;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.img-background:hover .block_drop {
  margin-top: -40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1">
  <div class="img-background">
    <a href="#" class="card-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/314x205/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Shopping Tours"><span class="card-link">Shopping Tours</span></a>
    <div class="block_drop"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать, причем чтоб ссылка ниже тоже меняла цвет, как на макете

Comment: так а где у Вас в разметке `.block_drop`?

Comment: этот блок должен появлятся потом, насколько я понял

Comment: только что добавил его в разметку к img-background тоже не сработало

Comment: Я конечно не профи в таком, но может надо создать блок(оранжевый с ценой) и тупо скрыть его пока что с помощью display: none;, а потом при наведении уже вновь его показать+там скорее всего нужна анимация.

Comment: `display` не подлежит анимации или трансформации

Comment: Ну вот. я попытался, сорян

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.tour {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 70vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tour__box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  
  background-color: black;
  /* прячем всё что выходит за размеры этого блока */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tour__info {
  align-self: flex-end;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  /* опускаем этот блок на всю его высоту вниз */
  transform: translateY(100%);
  
  background-color: #FF5722;
}

.tour__name {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tour:hover .tour__info{

  transform: translateY(0);
}

.tour:hover .tour__name{
  color: #FF5722;
}
```

```html
<div class="tour">
  <div class="tour__box">
    <div class='tour__info'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tour__name">Shopping Tours</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как все это в итоге сделать ссылкой?, чтоб при наведении на весь блок переходить на другую страницу?

Comment: @OlegNY ну сделай `tour` ссылкой

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не прансформируй   `margin || padding` это чревато...

```css
.card1 {
  width: 314px;
  height: 262px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-background {
  width: 314px;
  height: 205px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.card-img {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  width: 307px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block_drop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #5751C1;
  bottom:-100%;
  transition: bottom .5s;
}

.card1:hover .block_drop {
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1">
  <div class="img-background">
    <a href="#" class="card-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/314x205/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Shopping Tours"></a>

  </div>
  <div class="block_drop"><span class="card-link">Shopping Tours</span></div>
</div>
```